# Jersey ExceptionMapper implementations skipped on deploy

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey-2.0

In my pet project I have a simple jersey (v 2.13) resource that performs some crud operations, and the input is validated by hibernate-validator (v 5.0.1.Final). 
The problem is that while the junit tests works as expected, when I deploy the webapp all the ExceptionMapper implementations are ignored.

Here some details:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JsonResult<User> addUser(@Valid Userbean user) {
  //do stuff...
}
```

The validation is made by hibernate-validator.

the Userbean is annotate with:

```
@NotNull
private String password;
```

I've created an ExceptionMapper implementation:

```
@Provider
public class ValidationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ValidationException> {
   @Override
   public Response toResponse(ValidationException e) {
   return Response.status(422).build();
   }
}
```

Leaving aside that on validation the proper status code should be 400, my problem is that while in my junit-test everything goes fine...

```
        Userbean entity = new Userbean();
        entity.setUsername(username);

        Response response = target.path("users").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(entity));
        int status = response.getStatus();
        assertEquals(422 status);
```

...I cannot reproduce the same behaviour when I run it on tomcat (I've tried tomcat7 / tomcat 8 and also glassfish 4.1)

I always get a 400 status code instead of 422 and ValidationExceptionMapper is being skipped.

```
$ curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"username\":\"MrFoo\"}" http://localhost:8080/playground-webapp/jaxrs/jersey/users/
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... connected
> POST /playground-webapp/jaxrs/jersey/users/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 20
> 
* upload completely sent off: 20out of 20 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Language: en
< Content-Length: 990
< Date: Sun, 28 Dec 2014 15:07:34 GMT
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection #0
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Bad Request</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.52</h3></body></html>
```

The same call made on the test server works as expected:

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"username\":\"MrFoo\"}" http://localhost:8080/users/
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... Connessione rifiutata
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
> POST /users/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 20
> 
* upload completely sent off: 20out of 20 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 422
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Sun, 28 Dec 2014 15:05:35 GMT
< Content-Length: 94
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

the code of the server I use for junit is:

```
@Before
public void setUpClient() throws Exception {
    ResourceConfig rc = new UserResourceConfig();
    rc.property("contextConfig", appContext);
    server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, rc);
    server.start();
    ....
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your JSON is not valid...

Comment: My fault! all the ExceptionMapper implementations were ignored because I misconfigured them in the web.xml!